# Installing packages ubuntu

Tags: python, lxml, package

I tried this command in terminal:

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

But I get

```
Package python-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python

E: Unable to locate package libxml2-dev
E: Unable to locate package libxslt1-dev
E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I tried updating apt-get, still same problem.

Comment: Paste /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: root@vps19007:~# /etc/apt/sources.list
-bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied

Comment: root@vps19007:~# sudo /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo: /etc/apt/sources.list: command not found

Comment: `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: root@vps19007:~# sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

Comment: I got this and I still have the same problem listed on the thread.

Comment: @JakeAnderson, why are you trying to install libxml2 when it comes with xenial?

Comment: --> pip install lxml

Comment: lxml, libxml2-dev are all included in xenial

Comment: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?

Comment: I have no issues at all and I am using xenial, judging by the *Unable to locate package libxml2-dev* etc.. , it looks like you have managed to break something on the system

Comment: Maybe because the vps has 512 mb of ram

Comment: It has 256 mb ram and 256 mb VSWAP, I need confirmation that it is due to RAM capacity. I don't want to waste money upgrading.

Comment: This is why I hate linux, I will just keep using windows like I normally do.